# Does rotational motion also requires centripetal force like circular motion?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, rotation

We all know we need a centripetal force to do a circular motion, but is it the same case for rotational motion? If it is not, then how does the velocity vector changes without applying force? If yes, then how does a rotating body remain in rotational motion in space without any force?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but I'll try:

For a body rotating around some axis, the individual parts move on circular paths, and thus there needs to be a centripetal force. That force is just provided by the internal interatomic forces, i.e. the forces that hold the body together and keep it approximately rigid. If rotation becomes too fast, the outer parts of the body can be ripped off -- that is  a limiting factor for the rotational speeds of some angle grinders, for example.

For the second part of the question, the centripetal force is orthogonal to the direction of motion and so does not accelerate or brake the motion. Hence, the body will continue to move with the same angular velocity. Only if there is some external force acting away from the axis, producing a torque (e.g. the brake on a wheel), the rotation will slow down.